# Настройка виртуальной клавиатуры Android

Tags: android, c#, unity3d

При вводе текста на мобильном устройстве текст не отображается но он там и есть
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скорее всего он написан белым на белом. Как изменить цвет на чёрный?

Comment: Искали хоть? Вот [форум Unity](https://forum.unity.com/threads/keyboard-text-white.391322/), вроде с ответом...